# Mongo Aggregation of $where: function() using MongoTemplate in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I have written a mongo query which works in a mongo environment. I need to rewrite the same query using MongoTemplate in Spring. Tried a couple of ways, but it didn't work for me. Can anybody help me out with this problem? Thanks.

This is the mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('tenMinAggData_JAT').find({ $where: function(){ return (this.ET - this._id.ST) > 3600 }})
```